# вложенный блок и расстановка событий

Tags: javascript, html

есть блок и по событию клика на блок с `id="event1"` вешается 1 событие js.
при клике на блок c `id="close_event1"` соответствующее другое событие. Но так как первый блок - родитель второго, то и кликаем только на 1 блок в обеих вариантах. собственно вопрос в том как сделать, что бы повесить событие на вложенный блок, что бы не переносить его за пределы родителя, т.к. при клике на последний , должен прятаться родитель , и выходит не очень удобно

```
     <div class="main_block_participation">
        <div class="event_border" id="event1">            
            <div class="event_image">
                <img src="images/product/Без имени-1.jpg" />
                <div class="event_note">
                    <div id="event_calendar_left">Left</div>
                    <div id="event_calendar_count">#</div>
                    <div id="event_calendar_days">Days</div>
                </div>                    
            </div>                 
            <div class="event_close" id="close_event1">
                <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="event_date">19 December - 20 November</div>
                <div class="event_description">   text  text  text </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: не совсем ясно куда именно метод вписывать, в событие по родителю или по вложенному блоку

Comment: всё, разобрался, спасибо Вам)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы клик по дочернему блоку не вызвал клика по родительскому, вам необходимо добавить слушатель события click по этому элементу и применить функцию остановки всплытия события event.stopPropagation();

Comment: спасибо и Вам за отклик, @Deonis любезно подсказал уже)